# How to make datepicker control's value to blank?

Tags: asp.net

I have created a one form.In that form I am using gm's datepicker control.User can fill form and onreset button I want to clear all textboxes and datepicker control.I am able to clear textbox control but not datepicker control.How to do that?There are 5 section in my web page.Reset button is only for one section.I don't want redirect to same page on reset button.If I do like this,user can loose all 4 section value.I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Code-Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (!IsPostBack)
       {
                DatePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today; ;
       }
}
```

Markup

```
<asp:Calendar ID="DatePicker1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: I want to make it blank not current date...Gm datepicker does not have selected date property.